# CKEDITOR Image upload - fileUploadResponse event is not firing

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to integrate `CKEditor` in Angular App. In `CKEditor`, I am trying to use [uploadimage](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload). In run method of my app I have written following code to listen the events of `CKEditor`.

```
 CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( event ) {
            console.log("CKEditor instance created");
 });

  CKEDITOR.on( 'fileUploadResponse', function( evt ) {
                // Prevent the default response handler.
                console.log("Image Uploaded");
                evt.stop();

                // Ger XHR and response.
                var data = evt.data,
                    xhr = data.fileLoader.xhr,
                    response = xhr.responseText.split( '|' );

            if ( response[ 1 ] ) {
                // Error occurred during upload.
                data.message = response[ 1 ];
                evt.cancel();
            } else {
                data.url = response[ 0 ];
            }
            console.log("Image Uploaded");
 } );
```

In console it is printing `CKEditor instance created`, but not printing `Image Uploaded`. Somehow it is not listening to `fileUploadResponse` event.

My config file of CKEditor is as follow:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
    config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
    config.uploadUrl = '/notice/fileupload';
};
```

Everything is working fine and my image file is also uploading successfully and I am getting following JSON response:

```
{
    "uploaded": 1,
    "fileName": "checkout.PNG",
    "url": "/img/syllabus/checkout.PNG",
    "error": null
}
```

But `fileUploadResponse` is not firing after so many tries. I am not sure which part I am missing.

Answer (score 5):

I think the 'fileUploadResponse'-Event has to be registered on the ckeditor-instance and not on CKEDITOR itself.

```
var editor = $( 'textarea#editor1' ).ckeditor();
editor.on( 'fileUploadResponse', function( evt ) {...});
```

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin Schüller for highlighting my mistake. Based on that I am able to solve the issue using ng-ckeditor library. I have added the code in answer.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, @Benjamin Schüller for pointing in the right direction.

I am using [ng-ckeditor](https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor) library for CKEditor Textarea along with ng-model data. This library has the directive in which they are initiating the CKEditor instance. All I needed is to get that instance and register `fileUploadResponse` event to it.

Following is my textarea in template html:

```
<textarea id="noticeDetails" ckeditor="editorOptions" name="description" ng-model="ctrl.notice.description" ></textarea>
```

And in my Angular Controller, I am defining `editorOptions` and binding `fileUploadResponse`:

```
        $scope.editorOptions = {
            language: 'en',
            allowedContent: true,
            entities: false
        };

        $scope.$on("ckeditor.ready", function( event ) {                
            var noticeCkEditor = CKEDITOR.instances["noticeDetails"];
            noticeCkEditor.on( 'fileUploadResponse', function( evt ) {                      
                // Prevent the default response handler.
                evt.stop();

                // Get XHR and response.
                var data = evt.data,
                    xhr = data.fileLoader.xhr,
                    response = xhr.responseText;

                var respJson = angular.fromJson(response);
                console.log(respJson);

                if ( respJson.error ) {
                    // Error occurred during upload.
                    data.message = respJson.error.message;
                    evt.cancel();
                } else {                
                    data.url = respJson.url;
                }
            } );

        });
```

Following is my JSON response on file upload:

```
{
    "uploaded": 1,
    "fileName": "IMG_1202.PNG",
    "url": "/img/society/notice/IMG_1202.PNG",
    "error": null
}
```

Few things to note here:

1. You can get an instance after CKEditor completely initialized. [ng-ckeditor](https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor) has broadcast called `ckeditor.ready`. So on `ckeditor.ready` you can get an instance and bind events specific to the editor.
2. CKEditor gives name to the instance using id of the textarea. In my case id is `noticeDetails`, so it will create an instance with name `noticeDetails`. In case you have not given the id then it will create the instance with names `editor1`, `editor2` and so on. In my case, I am getting the CKEditor instance with `noticeDetails` name.
3. [CKEditor documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload) has mentioned example code to handle file upload response manually. But it is not working. They are binding whole JSON string to `data.message` or `data.url` which is not the way to do as per my experiment. What we need to do is create the JSON object from the response string and appropriately get the message or URL from that JSON object and bind it with data object as shown in the above code.